# Nesting a directive inside of a table

Tags: angularjs, directive

Is this possible? I want the ability to tidily swap out a table body depending on user input, so i just threw this little *test together to see if it would work, but it's loading all wonky, with the body preceding and exterior to the table itself in the DOM even though I nest it appropriately in my html. so my questions are thus: 
1) what's this behavior all about? and
2) can i achieve what I want the way i'm going about it?

*[simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23vajLmm/1/)

**html:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<table class="table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <my-directive></my-directive><!--  this should be the tbody -->
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
     <td>Sum</td>
     <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table> 
</div>
```

**js:**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<tbody><tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr><tr><td>February</td><td>$80</td></tr></tbody>',

    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently rendering markup within a `<my-directive></my-directive>` element, which is messing up the table layout.

Instead, change your directive to an attribute-based directive and place it on the `<tbody>` element, replacing the content..

Template

```
</thead>
<tbody my-directive></tbody><!--  this should be the tbody -->
<tfoot>
```

Directive

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<tr><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr><tr><td>February</td><td>$80</td></tr>'
};
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLvkabr7/).

Comment: @spb see update and working fiddle.  it would blow up with replace because it couldn't properly define the root element.  Replace wasn't the right solution.  Instead, just replace the inside contents of tbody.

Comment: and blow up it did. haha. thanks for the fix. you da best.

Comment: Yep yep, I blew it up at first as well :).  Not a problem, happy to help!